# How to write a function to insert object properties via for loop

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I'm trying to build an object to hold some data that I'm reading.

I'll always know exactly which data fields will be in the data and that they will always be in the same order. I need to extract the data though and I'm doing this one line at a time.

So the first time around there will be no data in my object, and it will have to build out each property based on the data that's being submitted.

```
function buildData (Data) {

    if(typeof myData.a === 'undefined'){
      myData.a = Data[i];
    }else{
      myData.a= myData.a + " " + Data[i];
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having here is that I want the `myDataArray` to determine which property will be used to insert the data into.

So a psudeo version of what I'm looking to do

```
function buildData (Data) {
  var myDataArray = [
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd',
    'e',
    'f'
  ]; 

  for(var i = 0; i < myDataArray.length; i++) {
    if(typeof myData.myDataArray[i] === 'undefined'){
      myData.myDataArray[i] = Data[i];
    }else{
      myData.myDataArray[i] = myData.myDataArray[i] + " " + Data[i];
    }
  };
```

However, this obviously inserts the data into a `myData.myDataArray` property of my object, how can I use the array to dynamically select the property to insert into, so that as the for loops goes through the length of the array, I get data inserted into `myData.a`, `myData.b`, `myData.c`, etc?

Comment: `myData[ myDataArray[i] ]`

Comment: @blex awesome thanks so much! I forgot that the Array prototype applies to objects!

Comment: That's a common error. Glad it helped you!